# Google Charts: How to overlay text message when dataset is empty?

Tags: google-visualization

I am charting selections made by the user.  When my page first loads there are no selections.

How do I show some text over the chart like below?

[image]

Note:

1. I don't care about the formatting - my screen capture tool adds that formatting
2. This is well documented for the depreciated Google Image Charts, but that doesn't help me

Comment: Any reason you can't just have a floating div appear on load, and hide it as soon as the user interacts? If you are looking for a chart option, none exists, and the kludge would likely be more awkward than just doing it with HTML, CSS, and jquery (or your preferred alternative)

Comment: Alright, I think that's the answer I needed.  thanks.